# Sort dictionary based on 2 factors

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, dictionary, compareto

I have a dictionary, it's key is a string, and the value is a list of objects. I want to sort its keys based on 2 factors, the size of the list, and the object Id. The values are sorted so the first element in the list is always the lowest id.

So far I managed to use order by to sort it by the number of elements in the list, but now I am having a hard time sorting based on the other factor.

Example: Dictionary X contains current keys/values

```
["A",{2,4,5,6}]
["B",{6}]   
["C",{1}]
["D",{0,1}]   
["E",{0,99,88,66}]
```

After sorting it should be

```
["E",{0,99,88,66}]
["A",{2,4,5,6}]    
["D",{0,1}]
["C",{1}]   
["B",{6}]
```

Here is what I have:

```
Public MyObject{
  public Int Id{ get; set;}
}

var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<MyObject>>();
var dictionarySortedByCount = dictionary.OrderBy(x => x.Value.Count).Reverse().ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't use a `Dictionary` for sorting, because the order of the dictionary is not sorted. It's optimized for looking-up keys. Store it in a `List` instead.

Comment: In OrderBy you can use whatever logic you like, so you can put a method that gives an IComparable value. But, as Jeroen mentioned, you destroy your order by putting it back to Dictionary. This class is always sorted like a real life dictionary (Hence its name)

Comment: Why would it destroy the order of the dictionary ? wouldn't my statement up there create new dictionary that is ordered per list size in each key ?

Comment: Dictionaries are not sorted. Dictionary elements have a key that makes lookup faster. It is not specified that a dictionary works using some sorting mechanism. When you do your sorting, you are not sorting the dictionary, but the elements in the dictionary. The result is a new sequence (containing the original objects). Real LINQ does not change the sequence in TSource, Only enumerating over the elements might change the elements in the sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried adding another order condition after the first one like below ?

```
var dictionarySortedByCount = dictionary
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Value.Count)
        .ThenBy(x => x.Value[0].ObjectId)
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Comment: No but I want to try this 
var dictionarySortedByCount = dictionary
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Value.Count)
        .ThenBy(x => x.Value[0].ObjectId)
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);

Comment: Being curious... Any specific reason to use ObjectId for sorting?

Comment: Your are right! I thought the second condition is the dictionary key :p. If it works let me know so I can edit the answer.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I am trying to sort the dictionary keys based on the number of the elemnts they contains, however I want a special case condition where if the element count is the same there would be the lowest Id to to use, so that keyvalue pair becomes first

Comment: @RajmondBurgaj I am in the process of testing :P

Comment: Your answer is correct, Using ThenBy was my solution, but not the key, the first element in the list